# Syntax and changing variable values

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax

There is a code snippet `turnset = False` in line 14 that displayed as invalid syntax but an exact replica is in line 5 and works fine!
Code here:

```
X = "X"
O = "O"
w = "none"
board = [N, N, N, N, N, N, N, N, N]
win = False
turn = input("Player 1 first?")
p1 = input("Player 1:")
p2 = input("Player 2:")
print(" ")
for turns in range (9
 if (turn)
  turn = False
  print(p1 + "'s turn!")
  x = input("X coordinates:")
  y = input("Y coordinates:")
  pos = (y - 1) * 3 + x - 1
  board[pos] = X
 else:
  turn = True
  if False: 
   print(p2 + "'s turn!")
   x = input("X coordinates:")
   y = input("Y coordinates:")
   pos = (y - 1) * 3 + x - 1
   board[pos] = O
  print(board[0] + board[1] + board[2])
  print(board[3] + board[4] + board[5])
  print(board[6] + board[7] + board[8])
  tile = X
  if ((board[0] == tile and board[1] == tile and board[2] == tile) or (board[3] == tile and board[4] == tile and board[5] == tile) or (board[6] == tile and board[7] == tile and board[8] == tile) or ((board[0] == tile and board[3] == tile and board[6] == tile) or (board[1] == tile and board[4] == tile and board[7] == tile) or (board[2] == tile and board[5] == tile and board[8] == tile) or ((board[0] == tile and board[4] == tile and board[8] == tile) or (board[2] == tile and board[4] == tile and board[6] == tile))
   w = p1
  
   break
  tile = O
  if ((board[0] == tile and board[1] == tile and board[2] == tile) or (board[3] == tile and board[4] == tile and board[5] == tile) or (board[6] == tile and board[7] == tile and board[8] == tile) or ((board[0] == tile and board[3] == tile and board[6] == tile) or (board[1] == tile and board[4] == tile and board[7] == tile) or (board[2] == tile and board[5] == tile and board[8] == tile) or ((board[0] == tile and board[4] == tile and board[8] == tile) or (board[2] == tile and board[4] == tile and board[6] == tile))
   w = p2
  break
 if (w != "none")
  print(w + "won!")
 else
  print("Tie!")
```

Comment: Hint: What is the difference between the code that came before line 5 and the code that came before line 14?

Comment: Are you certain that `for turns in range (9` is correct? Hint #2: it's not.

Answer (score 1):

Every indented code block must be following a colon *(`:`)* at the end of the previous line, so the `for` loop and the `if` statements must end with a colon. When a line gets too long, you can add linebreaks like so *(and in doing so to your code I found some bracket inconsistencies that I fixed below)*:

```
X = "X"
O = "O"
w = "none"
board = [N, N, N, N, N, N, N, N, N]
win = False
turn = input("Player 1 first?")
p1 = input("Player 1:")
p2 = input("Player 2:")
print(" ")
for turns in range(9):
 if (turn):
  turn = False
  print(p1 + "'s turn!")
  x = input("X coordinates:")
  y = input("Y coordinates:")
  pos = (y - 1) * 3 + x - 1
  board[pos] = X
 else:
  turn = True
  if False: 
   print(p2 + "'s turn!")
   x = input("X coordinates:")
   y = input("Y coordinates:")
   pos = (y - 1) * 3 + x - 1
   board[pos] = O
  print(board[0] + board[1] + board[2])
  print(board[3] + board[4] + board[5])
  print(board[6] + board[7] + board[8])
  tile = X
  if ((board[0] == tile and board[1] == tile and board[2] == tile) or \
      (board[3] == tile and board[4] == tile and board[5] == tile) or \
      (board[6] == tile and board[7] == tile and board[8] == tile) or \
      (board[0] == tile and board[3] == tile and board[6] == tile) or \
      (board[1] == tile and board[4] == tile and board[7] == tile) or \
      (board[2] == tile and board[5] == tile and board[8] == tile) or \
      (board[0] == tile and board[4] == tile and board[8] == tile) or \
      (board[2] == tile and board[4] == tile and board[6] == tile)):
   w = p1
  
   break
  tile = O
  if ((board[0] == tile and board[1] == tile and board[2] == tile) or \
      (board[3] == tile and board[4] == tile and board[5] == tile) or \
      (board[6] == tile and board[7] == tile and board[8] == tile) or \
      (board[0] == tile and board[3] == tile and board[6] == tile) or \
      (board[1] == tile and board[4] == tile and board[7] == tile) or \
      (board[2] == tile and board[5] == tile and board[8] == tile) or \
      (board[0] == tile and board[4] == tile and board[8] == tile) or \
      (board[2] == tile and board[4] == tile and board[6] == tile)):
   w = p2
  break
 if (w != "none"):
  print(w + "won!")
 else:
  print("Tie!")
```

Finally, note that it's according to [PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) to use 4 spaces as the indentation rather than 1.